# Will MTU increase affect all parties?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, mtu

Will a Maximum Transfer Unit (MTU) increase for the ethernet interface on one device, `box-a` pictured below, in a LAN network also increase the MTU between each of the clients and `box-a`?

[image]

Put another way, is this setting least- or most-common-denominator?  How can I prove the setting took effect other than looking at an updated value output with `ifconfig eth1`?

I hope to be able to build a test network and validate, but it will take some some to acquire hardware.

On `box-a`:

```
ip a list eth1
ip link set mtu 1400 dev eth1
ip a list eth1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not automatically increase MTU of the other devices, they should just communicate with the smaller MTU. But it can lead to problems, with devices which cant handle it.
I am as example had problems with DHCP over APs on a network, where the DHCP Server was the one with the increased MTU.